# Additional Tab on page reload

Tags: bug, new-nav

I created and saved a custom tab. I called it 'favorite' and it looks just fine:
[image]

Then, when I manually reload the page, I get an additional tab with the same content and the name '*newest (multiple tags)' which I think should not happen:
[image]

After that, when I wait until the page starts displaying the 'x new questions' info, it switches back to only one tab:
[image]

(Observed on Firefox 51.0.1 (64-Bit))

**Edit:**

The additional tab only appears when the custom tab 'favorite' is selected at the time I reload the page.

**Edit2:**

While the additional tab is visible, the custom tab 'favorite' cannot be selected.